# I am trying to build a concurrent counter program where the performance time increases when the thread increases

Tags: c, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ck_pr.h>

struct counter_handle {
    uint64_t value;
    struct counter_handle *next;
};

struct counter {
    struct counter_handle *counters;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
};

struct counter *
counter_create(void)
{
    struct counter *r = calloc(sizeof *r, 1);

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&r->mutex, NULL) != 0)
            goto fail;

    return r;
fail:
    free(r);
    return NULL;
}

void
counter_inc(struct counter_handle *counter)
{
     ck_pr_store_64(&counter->value, counter->value + 1);
     return;
}

unsigned long
counter_read(struct counter *counter)
{
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    for (struct counter_handle *cursor = counter->counters;
            cursor != NULL;
            cursor  = cursor->next) {
               sum += ck_pr_load_64(&cursor->value);
    }

    return (unsigned long)sum;

  }

  struct counter_handle *
  counter_handle_create(struct counter *counter)
  {
    struct counter_handle *r = calloc(sizeof(*r), 1);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&counter->mutex);
    r->next = counter->counters;
    counter->counters = r;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&counter->mutex);
 }
```

This is my code. When I try to compile it, it is compiling but when I run the benchmark program it's giving me a segmentation fault. I am not sure what exactly wrong with the code. When I compile the performance time should increase as the number of thread increases. Someone please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program to fix the crash? Have you used a debugger to catch the crash so you know when and where in your code it happens?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ahh thanks, I will do that and see